# Passing a global variable to a function from a dropdown menu selection

Tags: javascript, function, drop-down-menu, global-variables, listener

I have a program with several dropdown menues, each stored in a single array for simplicity.  I need to create an event that activates when a new option is selected. here is what I tried:

```
  questionFormatList[counter] = document.createElement( "select" );
  questionFormatList[counter].id = counter;
  questionFormatList[ counter ].text = "Multiple Choice";

  //fill the dropdown menu with the four options
  for( var j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
  {
     questionFormatListOptions = document.createElement( "option" );
     dropDownMenuQuestionTextNode = document.createTextNode( questionTypes[ j ] );
     questionFormatListOptions.appendChild( dropDownMenuQuestionTextNode );
     questionFormatList[ counter ].appendChild( questionFormatListOptions );
  }
questionFormatList[counter].addEventListener( "change", function(){alteredSelection(questionFormatList[ counter ] );});
```

It is just ignoring it though. The three variables are global. Please advise. I am not a pro so maybe it is something simple. I am assuming it is something with the listener.

Comment: Are you trying to use the value of `counter` when you create the event listener? or do you actually want to use the global value of `counter`? i.e. if `counter = 1` when you run the above code, then `counter` changes to `2`. Do you want to return `questionFormatList[1]` or `questionFormatList[2]`?

Comment: I am trying to have it send its respective counter value to the function. the counter is continually increased (it's also global); but I assign its value to the id of each element which I reference in the function later.

Comment: cepharum's answer should give you the right `counter` value, but still not sure on what is not working. I'm assuming your also adding the `questionFormatList[counter]` to the DOM at some point, and not expecting the event to be bound to an existing element on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling addEventListener on lastly created selection menu. if you want to call 
event listener on all three select menus try.

```
selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
for( var j = 0; j < select.length; j++ )
{
  selects[i].addEventListener('change',function(){alteredSelection(selects[j])},false);
}
```

this will enable eventlistener on all the selects. keep the habit of looking the problem in console and make use of console.log and console.dir. It has always helped me. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by Akurn your issue is due to improperly using closure-scope variable counter. Try using this code instead of your last line:

```
(function(list) {
    list.addEventListener( "change", function() {
        alteredSelection(list);
    } );
})(questionFormatList[counter]);
```

This is binding result of `questionFormatList[counter]` to its actual value on adding event listener.

BTW: lines 3 and 4 of your code are writing to property `.text` multiply.

Comment: First, thanks for the time. Second thanks for the last point. I have done so much with this program over the last couple weeks that that snuck in. Third, I did a straight copy paste but no success. Is there any thing I have to do before it?

Comment: Instead of adding an IIFE, can't you just use `this`, since your referring to the element that the event is called from: `questionFormatList[counter].addEventListener( "change", function(){alteredSelection( this );});`